# how to scrape table data using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
executable_path=r'C:\Users\Kashi\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.mql5.com/en/quotes/currencies')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="list-view-btn"]').click()
time.sleep(15)
values = [[ [] for c in range(4)] for r in range(4)]

def scrape():
    for i in range (2,8):
        if i%2 == 0 :
            ask = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticker_ask_ + str(i) + "]').text
            values[i][0].append(ask)
            bid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticker_bid_ + str(i) + "]').text
            values[i][1].append(bid)
            high = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticker_high_ + str(i) + "]').text
            values[i][2].append(high)
            low = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticker_low_ + str(i) + "]').text
            values[i][3].append(low)
            print ( values[i][0] ,' , ',values[i][1] ,' , ',values[i][2] ,' , ',values[i][3]  )
scrape()
```

How can I scrape multiple rows data using Selenium? As I'm unable to scrape multiple rows data. I'm using Jupyter Notebook and Python 3. And I'm getting this error :

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ticker_ask_ + str(i) + "]"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can make use of `{}` to define i in `find_elements` :

try this instead :

```
values = [[ [] for c in range(4)] for r in range(4)]
def scrape():
    for i in range(2, 8):
      if i % 2 == 0:
        ask = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[@id='ticker_ask_{i}']").text
        values[i][0].append(ask)
        bid = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[@id='ticker_bid_{i}']").text
        values[i][1].append(bid)
        high = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[@id='ticker_high_{i}']").text
        values[i][2].append(high)
        low = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//*[@id='ticker_low_{i}']").text
        values[i][3].append(low)
        print(values[i][0], ' , ', values[i][1], ' , ', values[i][2], ' , ', values[i][3])
scrape()
```

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ticker_ask_ + 2"]"}

Comment: @KashifHussain : updated the post above, do check it out and let me know

Comment: The downside with this solution is that it will break once the HTML structure will be changed. Using the API calls (against `https://www.mql5.com/en/quotes/symbols/json`) can solve this problem.

Comment: @balderman : this was basically to parse the `i` in xpath in python, if locators are correct then it's a good to go approach

Comment: @cruisepandey While the scraping is simple enough (I agree) it is always safer and cleaner to call API (if there is one). In this case there is an API endpoint. Why not using it?

Answer (score 3):

You can run HTTP POST requests against the endpoint `https://www.mql5.com/en/quotes/symbols/json`. This endpoint return the data to the browser.
Do F12 in your browser, Network->Fetch/XHR.
Navigate in the "Currency exchange rates" table and see the HTTP POST requests the are initiated from the browser.

curl example below

```
curl 'https://www.mql5.com/en/quotes/symbols/json' \
  -H 'authority: www.mql5.com' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'origin: https://www.mql5.com' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://www.mql5.com/en/quotes/currencies' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,el;q=0.8,he;q=0.7,de;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,it;q=0.4,es;q=0.3' \
  -H 'cookie: sid=21maju3l3pnzvqri0chcalbt; lang=en; _fz_uniq=5044349715386065060; _fz_fvdt=1628597925; _fz_ssn=1628597925063698947' \
  --data-raw 'symbols=EURCAD%2CCADCHF%2CNZDCAD%2CCADMXN&__signature=245f9caa9d5d04eac315c5ade7b83b55' \
  --compressed
```

response

```
[{"id":17,"name":"EURCAD","description":"Euro vs Canadian Dollar","chart":"1.47673,1.47261,1.47932,1.48741,1.48959,1.50352,1.49338,1.48128,1.47798,1.47882,1.48048,1.48890,1.48325,1.47912,1.47983,1.48445,1.48709,1.48405,1.47919,1.47668,1.47562,1.47286","c1":"eu","c2":"ca","growth":0.00262754097470208,"digits":5,"ask":1.47286,"bid":1.47286,"dir":0,"chart_date":1626037200},{"id":20,"name":"CADCHF","description":"Canadian Dollar vs Swiss Franc","chart":"0.73461,0.73344,0.73135,0.72833,0.72851,0.71856,0.72641,0.72995,0.73079,0.73165,0.72877,0.72525,0.72563,0.72739,0.72601,0.72309,0.72052,0.72282,0.72435,0.72856,0.73064,0.73375","c1":"ca","c2":"ch","growth":0.00117206132879044,"digits":5,"ask":0.73375,"bid":0.73375,"dir":0,"chart_date":1626037200},{"id":552,"name":"NZDCAD","description":"New Zealand Dollar vs Canadian Dollar","chart":"0.86911,0.86889,0.87900,0.87887,0.88323,0.88483,0.87695,0.87441,0.87577,0.87663,0.87799,0.87630,0.87097,0.87216,0.86933,0.87092,0.87939,0.88297,0.88116,0.88022,0.87925,0.87885","c1":"nz","c2":"ca","growth":0.0112068667947671,"digits":5,"ask":0.87885,"bid":0.87885,"dir":0,"chart_date":1626037200},{"id":21412,"name":"CADMXN","description":"Canadian Dollar vs Mexican Peso","chart":"15.90559,15.90099,15.89632,15.89409,15.72787,15.78864,15.98092,15.98750,15.95864,15.95734,15.92996,15.92746,15.90106,15.83825,15.82930,15.94008,15.95096","c1":"ca","c2":"mx","growth":0.00285245627480646,"digits":5,"ask":15.95096,"bid":15.95096,"dir":0,"chart_date":1626037200}]a
```

Comment: @KashifHussain - it does work. You should call using HTTP POST with the proper arguments. (not HTTP GET)

Comment: i did'nt get it, but Thank You for responding

Comment: Let me rephrase. You can get the data you are looking for by doing HTTP calls against the endpoint I mentioned. You dont need to do any scraping operation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
def scrape():
    for i in range (2,8):
        if i%2 == 0 :
            ask = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticker_ask_" + str(i) + "]"').text
            values[i][0].append(ask)
            bid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticker_bid_" + str(i) + "]"').text
            values[i][1].append(bid)
            high = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticker_high_" + str(i) + "]"').text
            values[i][2].append(high)
            low = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ticker_low_" + str(i) + "]"').text
            values[i][3].append(low)
            print ( values[i][0] ,' , ',values[i][1] ,' , ',values[i][2] ,' , ',values[i][3]  )
scrape()
```

Comment: InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id="ticker_ask_" + str(i) + "] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id="ticker_ask_" + str(i) + "]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id="ticker_ask_" + str(i) + "]" because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id="ticker_ask_" + str(i) + "]"' is not a valid XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use below code to scrape that website.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.mql5.com/en/quotes/currencies")
driver.find_element_by_id("list-view-btn").click()
time.sleep(2)
tabledata = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr")
for table in tabledata:
    time.sleep(2)
    title = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'descr')]").text
    ask = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@id,'ask')]").text
    bid = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@id,'bid')]").text
    high = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@id,'high')]").text
    low = table.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@id,'low')]").text
    print("{}: {},{},{},{}".format(title,ask,bid,high,low))
```